# How to combine arc diff and fastlane?

Tags: ios, fastlane, phabricator, arcanist

How to combine arc diff and fastlane?
arc diff requires a message and a description of the commit, but when running the fastlane script, the command line does not allow you to enter a message.
Has anyone tried to combine arcanist phabricator + fastlane?

Comment: Please, put more details! Otherwise, it'll be impossible to help you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with fastlane, so excuse me if this response is not technically feasible for some reason, but I would think the way to integrate fastlane into your Phabricator workflow would be to run it server side triggered by Herald rules that start Harbormaster builds or webhooks to trigger builds on an external build server.